# I am trying to push my changes upto my online repository, using "git push" command. But it is just not working

Tags: git, github, push

```
git remote add origin https:/github.com/bitchimmadonna/Repository1.git

git commit -m "Add Sundae icecream!"

git push
```

The error shown is:

> *warning: push.default is unset; its implicit value has changed in
>   Git 2.0 from 'matching' to 'simple'. To squelch this message
>   and maintain the traditional behavior, use:
>     git config --global push.default matching
>   To squelch this message and adopt the new behavior now, use:
>     git config --global push.default simple
>   When push.default is set to 'matching', git will push local branches
>   to the remote branches that already exist with the same name.
>   Since Git 2.0, Git defaults to the more conservative 'simple'
>   behavior, which only pushes the current branch to the corresponding
>   remote branch that 'git pull' uses to update the current branch.
>   See 'git help config' and search for 'push.default' for further information.
>   (the 'simple' mode was introduced in Git 1.7.11. Use the similar mode
>   'current' instead of 'simple' if you sometimes use older versions of Git)
>   fatal: The current branch master has no upstream branch.
>   To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use
>       git push --set-upstream origin master*

I got comments recommending to use git push --set-upstream origin master. But I am sorry, this too failed.

Comment: `git push -u origin master`

Comment: In the error log: To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use git push --set-upstream origin master.

Comment: already tried it, not working still. git push -u origin master
ssh: Could not resolve hostname https: Temporary failure in name resolution
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: `https:/` vs `https://`?

Comment: `git remote set-url origin https://github.com/` etc.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> git remote add origin https:/github.com/bitchimmadonna/Repository1.git
> git push -u origin master
> ```
>
> ssh: Could not resolve hostname https: Temporary failure in name resolution fatal: Could not read from remote repository. Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.

It seems like the URL you used is wrong, you're saying `https:/` instead of `https://`. To change the URL, do

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/bitchimmadonna/Repository1.git
```

Now

```
git push -u origin master
```

should work as expected.